# Unable to run a project in Eclipse IDE in Mac

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

While trying to run a project in Eclipse IDE, it is showing an error popup, saying that "An error has occurred". How to resolve this?

I tried updating the eclipse IDE, but it didn't work.

Note : I am facing this issue only after the OS update.

Using Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers version : Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a), running on macOS Monterey (12.3.1).

[image]

Comment: Click on detail so you can see where the error happens.

Comment: @ChengThao It is not showing anything on clicking Details button

Comment: Try Eclipse error log to see if you find anything.  https://code2care.org/howto/view-eclipse-error-log

Comment: IDE is not at all working, error log panel is not showing anything. If I click anything in the IDE it shows the error popup.

Comment: Eclipse Oxygen is 5 years and 17 releases old, you need to be running the current Eclipse 2022-06 to work properly on macOS.

Answer (score 0):

I installed the latest version of Eclipse IDE, and it resolved my problem.